# QuickFIX Examples won't build on Ubuntu 11.04 / C++

Tags: quickfix

I am trying to build the examples on Ubuntu 11.04 but all I get from the Makefile is a bunch of errors:

./Makefile: line 18: datadir: command not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command

Is it possible to build those examples under Linux or the examples are meant to be built only on Win/VC++?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you following the steps listed down here ? http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/building.html#Linux%20/%20Solaris%20/%20FreeBSD%20/%20Mac%20OS%20X%20(C++/Java)

Comment: If it's SOLVED, please delete it if you're not going to provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that

Building under *nix requires two steps. First, in the root quickfix directory, type ./configure This will probe your system to find out what functionality it supports for use in determining how to build QuickFIX. After ./configure completes succesfully, simply type make to build. If you run into problems running configure, you may need to run the ./bootstrap script first.

was the solution (saeems a valid answer with which to close the question as answered)